# Как перевести понятие "бесконечно большая" на английский язык?

Tags: переводы

Известно, что "бесконечно малая" переводится как Infinitesimal. Каким будет перевод сочетания "бесконечно большая"?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что с эти надо на английский язык идти.

Answer (score 1):

infinite мат., infinite quantity. Эти варианты зафиксированы в словаре ABBYY Lingvo.

Answer (score 0):

[Мириам-Уэбстер](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infinitesimal) и другие словари содержат достаточно антонимов к слову *infinitesimal*, из которых можно выбрать подходящий по контексту вариант.  Если нет ограничения использовать только одно слово, то я бы предложил *infinitely large*.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, однако хотел бы узнать перевод именно для математического термина "бесконечно большая". Предложенные антонимы не носят такой характер. Впрочем, мне кажется, что точного перевода этого термина не существует.

Comment: Мне попадалось написание этих слов через дефис.  Слово "infinite" - это прилагательное, возможно, удастся его использовать.  Есть также термин "approaching infinity".  Нужен контекст.